# Drupal - include taxonomy term descriptions in search

Tags: drupal, search, taxonomy

I am working on a large site which has around 600 taxonomy terms in one of its taxonomy vocabularies, each with the description field populated.

It's important that the search mechanism searches these term descriptions as well as the nodes themselves.

Drupal does not appear to be doing this by default - is there any way I can do this - any modules for example?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a ready made solution for this, so you will need to do custom development.

Your best bet is, with a big site and maybe 100k nodes to use apache solr to power your search. The default Drupal search is not made for searching a lot of data and will quickly become slow.

There is a Drupal module for apache solr search, and it does a lot of the heavy lifting and provides some hooks you can use. So with some code to build on that you should be able to vet such a search.

Solr does other nice things like faceted search.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I shall look into this, sounds good. In the meantime I'd lie to get Drupal's search doing it to extend my own knowledge (I've not developed search yet). Should I be looking to add the descriptions to the index, tell tue search to take them into account, or both?

Either way could you give me q hint about which hooks to look at? Thanks again!

Comment: I've not done this yet, buyt intend to try this method. Having researched it it looks like it will do what I' after, so chosen answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think there may already be a couple of ready made solutions

http://drupal.org/project/search_config

http://drupal.org/project/Custom_Search

Comment: Thanks, I've used these, however has not seen any way to include taxonomy descriptions in the searh results by using them...